# MySQL on Mac Monterey - my.cnf configuration changes are not being implemented in instance

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL on Mac. I am trying to change the configuration variable secure-file-priv, however changes I make to the my.cnf file are not actually being configured.

1. Using MySQL Workbench, I created an options file, which is located at /etc/my.cnf.

[image: Configuration panel]

2. I made changes to the configuration file in MySQL Workbench (Changing secure-file-priv)
3. I restarted my instance.
4. In terminal, I ran the command "cat '/etc/my.cnf'" to verify and confirm that changes I made to the my.cnf file in MySQL workbench were made.

Output:

[mysqld]

..secure-file-priv = '*MY SPECIFIED DIRECTORY*'

5. in mysql in terminal, I ran the command "SHOW VARIABLES;" to see if the configuration changes had taken effect in mysql. They had not.

Output:

...secure-file-priv = NULL

6. This confirmed that /etc/my.cnf file was not being read in by mysql
7. I also tried to specify the path of my configuration file in the MySQL section of system preferences, however this caused the instance to stop, and would not turn back on until I removed the configuration file path.

[image: MySQL in System preference]

8. I have confirmed that there are no other my.cnf files present on my Mac.

Stuck on what is best to do next to remediate this.